# Angular Material date picker error

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm trying to use md-datepicker component unfortunately i'm seeing some errors in console.

**HTML Code:**

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="vm.addfamilymember.dob" 
               md-placeholder="Date of Birth">
</md-datepicker>
```

**Console Error**

```
angular.min.js:118 Error: The ng-model for md-datepicker must be a Date instance. Currently the model is a: string
    at Error (native)
```

Comment: Try setting `vm.addfamilymember.dob` to `new Date()` in your controller

Answer (score 1):

$scope.vm.addfamilymember.dob = new Date(); do this in controller

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
It worked finally by adding
ng-change="vm.addfamilymember.dob = dt.toLocaleDateString()"